# parsing all json parametr and subset

Tags: php, json

```
  {"result":"success","totalresults":2,"products":{"product":[{"pid":"1","gid":"1","type":"hostingaccount","name":"test1","description":"","module":"cpanel","paytype":"onetime","pricing":{"USD":{"prefix":"$","suffix":" USD","msetupfee":"0.00","qsetupfee":"0.00","ssetupfee":"0.00","asetupfee":"0.00","bsetupfee":"0.00","tsetupfee":"0.00","monthly":"0.00","quarterly":"0.00","semiannually":"0.00","annually":"-1.00","biennially":"-1.00","triennially":"-1.00"}},"customfields":{"customfield":[]},"configoptions":{"configoption":[]}},{"pid":"2","gid":"1","type":"other","name":"javad host","description":"","module":"","paytype":"recurring","pricing":{"USD":{"prefix":"$","suffix":" USD","msetupfee":"12.00","qsetupfee":"25.00","ssetupfee":"0.00","asetupfee":"0.00","bsetupfee":"0.00","tsetupfee":"0.00","monthly":"24.00","quarterly":"26.00","semiannually":"-1.00","annually":"-1.00","biennially":"-1.00","triennially":"-1.00"}},"customfields":{"customfield":[]},"configoptions":{"configoption":[]}}]}}
```

this is my json - i pars with this code :

```
<?php
$url = 'http://safemode.acloud.ir/rasanegar/currencly.php';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($content, true);

foreach($json['products']['product']as $item) {
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>'.$item['pid'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$item['type'].'</td>';
echo '</tr>';
}?>
```

but i can pars the product json , like 'pid' , 'gid' , i cant pars pricing subset like 'prefix', 'monthly'

Comment: `foreach($item['pricing']['USD'] as $priceKey => $priceValue) {...}`

Answer (score 0):

Why do we need investigate your data structure for you?

Do it yourself next time please:

```
{"result":"success",
"totalresults":2,
"products":{
    "product":[
        {
            "pid":"1",
            "gid":"1",
            "type":"hostingaccount",
            "name":"test1",
            "description":"",
            "module":"cpanel",
            "paytype":"onetime",
            "pricing":{
                "USD":{
                    "prefix":"$",
                    "suffix":" USD",
                    "msetupfee":"0.00",
                    "qsetupfee":"0.00",
                    "ssetupfee":"0.00",
                    "asetupfee":"0.00",
                    "bsetupfee":"0.00",
                    "tsetupfee":"0.00",
                    "monthly":"0.00",
                    "quarterly":"0.00",
                    "semiannually":"0.00",
                    "annually":"-1.00",
                    "biennially":"-1.00",
                    "triennially":"-1.00"
                }
            },
            "customfields":{
                "customfield":[]
            },
            "configoptions":{
                "configoption":[]
            }
        },
....
```

so as @MarkBaker wrote in comment:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://safemode.acloud.ir/rasanegar/currencly.php';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($content, true);

foreach($json['products']['product']as $item) {
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>'.$item['pid'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$item['type'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$item['pricing']['USD']['prefix'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$item['pricing']['USD']['monthly'].'</td>';
echo '</tr>';
}?>
```

Comment: but i not forced u to answer my question - i just need help - if u didnt want to help me , Do not help next time ! but tanx for helping now